# Производительность comet технологий

Tags: comet, javascript

Что лучше использовать для создания как можно большой производительности (что даёт меньшую нагрузку на сервер) при реализации comet технологий: Node.js, dklab realplexor, DaemonPHP, WebSockets? Что порекомендуете использовать?

Comment: comet-технологии - это целый комплекс, что конкретно вы имеет ввиду, какую реализацию?

Comment: Наименьшую нагрузку на сервер дают прямые руки, даже когда используется php )

Comment: @Shadow, угу, перефразирую немного: "пока в Виллабаджо решают, какая технология даст 0.000001% прироста производительности, в Вилларива уже написали Facebook на пыхе".

Answer (score 2):

Почти все эти решения — event-based — в той или иной форме обертка над epoll/kqueue с реактором. Вопросы их производительности с наибольшей вероятностью упрутся в бизнес-логику (реализуемую Вами), а не особенности реализации event loop'а. Некоторое исключение из всего только системы на Erlang с его легковесными процессами (кстати, вариант на рассмотрение за одни уже network transparency и hot code swapping).

Лучше выбирайте то, на чем быстрее и удобнее сделаете продукт. А когда будет 100500 одновременных клиентов и дело будет грозить упереться в comet (рискну предположить, что намного раньше оно рискует упреться в БД или веб-страницы) — можно будет или добавить еще один сервер (горизонтальное масштабирование) или пересмотреть решение и постепенно выпустить новую версию.

Закладывайте слабое связывание (отсутствие привязки к конкретному языку/технологии), мониторинг и поддержку горизонтального масштабирования — не ошибетесь.